# RHEV SPICE console in IE8 fails to start

Tags: linux, virtualization, internet-explorer-8, rhev

I've got an issue with the fabulous Internet Explorer browser when working with Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization manager.

When in IE8, I click the "console" in RHEV administrator portal, the RHEV SPICE console is always going to be downloaded from the page and then installed (again and again on each click), instead of starting the console application to connect to the virtual host.. The SPICE console installation performs ok and it even can be started from C:\Program Files\Redhat directly, but it must be started from the RHEV web portal page to work properly.

I feel that such kind of issues can be browser settings related but I have played with almost all the options in Internet Explorer and it didn't have any effect.

Comment: What did Red Hat support say about this when you called them?

Comment: @Michael Hampton
Actually i haven't now a support ID to make the request to Red Hat service.
Anyway, I guess it could be common issue for the browsers when we click on the URL it renders content in the browser window, but sometimes it invokes a Run/Download dialog.
I know it is "Content Type" option of the server response, but I believe some browsers can interpert it in their unique way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. IE8 is not supported for webadmin access - it's javascript render
   engine is too slow to be useful. Use a newer browser or Firefox from
   Linux
2. the spice console client is an activeX control, you might need to add the webadmin to the trusted sites and enable activeX (some IE updates block it)
3. sometimes windows refuses to just run a new activeX, especially, one
   that wasn't signed by MS, and a client machine restart usually
   helps.
4. for a really useful answer (instead of a lot of guesswork), you need to contact RHT support